# After installing CodeIgniter its source code is showing on the webpage

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

After installing CodeIgniter, its source code is showing on the webpage. How to fix it?

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: You don't have PHP installed/enabled on the server.

Comment: thanks now working fine after executing below command on terminal php was not enabled on server ..  sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php

Comment: How about posting an answer?  You can also accept your own answer two days after posting the question, which will help others with a similar problem by indicating that the problem is solved and there is a proven solution here.